# How to get the value when clicking (loop value)?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I'm creating web page that fetch values from database, there are several values will be display. On each value, it will have textarea and button Tweet below. I want when user click on button tweet, it will catch the value from textarea above that button. For now, it will catch only the value from the first textarea when user click on button Tweet (all buttons).

**Here is my code**

**PHP**

```
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
    echo "<textarea style='margin-bottom:10px;' id='text_tweet' name='text_tweet' 
    cols='61' rows='5'></textarea>";
    echo "<a style='text-decoration: none; color: #000000;' id='tweet'
          href='#'>Tweet</a>";
}
```

**Javascript**

```
$("#tweet").bind('click', function(){
var text_tweet = $("#text_tweet").val();
if(text_tweet==""){
    alert("Please fill out something");
}
else{
    save_tweet(text_tweet);
}
});
```

Can anyone help me to solve this problem?

Thank in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You need to distinguish between each row that is being looped out. Here's an alternate approach assuming that `$row` has an `id`.

PHP

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
    echo "<textarea style='margin-bottom:10px;' id='text_tweet_" . $row['id'] . "' name='text_tweet_" . $row['id'] . "' cols='61' rows='5'></textarea>";
    echo "<a onclick='doSomething(" . $row['id'] . ")' style='text-decoration: none; color: #000000;' id='tweet_" . $row['id'] . "' href='#'>Tweet</a>";
}
```

JS

```
function doSomething(id) {
    var text_tweet = $("#text_tweet_" + id).val();
    if (text_tweet == "") {
        alert("Please fill out something");
    } else {
        save_tweet(text_tweet);
    }
}
```

Comment: +1, [id attributes **must** be unique](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/global.html#h-7.5.2). The anchor is still using the same id though.

Answer (score 0):

First off, if you're going to try and grab more than one element on a page, you can't use `id` as that's reserved for single elements - you should never have more than one element with the same `id`

First, I would change it so that each element has a class called 'tweet' on it. You will also need to add the jQuery `$(function(){})` around it. That function tells the browser not to run that JavaScript until the page and all elements have completely loaded.

I would also make sure to add a container around both the elements, this will make it easier for you to actually grab the textarea that is beside the the link.

Here's how I would handle it:

```
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
    echo "<div>";
    echo "<textarea style='margin-bottom:10px;' id='text_tweet' name='text_tweet' 
    cols='61' rows='5'></textarea>";
    echo "<a style='text-decoration: none; color: #000000;' class='tweet'
          href='#'>Tweet</a>";
    echo "</div>";
}
```

And then the javascript:

```
$(function() {

$(".tweet").bind('click', function(){
var text_tweet = $(this).parents('div:first').find("textarea").val();
if(text_tweet==""){
    alert("Please fill out something");
}
else{
    save_tweet(text_tweet);
}
});

});
```

The reason we do `$(this).parents('div:first').find("textarea").val()` is because we want to grab the textarea within that containing div only; otherwise, jQuery will grab the first textarea value in the array.